# Solving a linear equation $Y=mX+c$ with $X,Y \in \mathbb{Z}$ but $m,c \in \mathbb{J}$ (are irrational)

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, independence

I'm having trouble solving the equation as in the title. I'm seeking to determine if there exists a solution, and if so, to find the solution (which I have proved is unique, i.e. there is at most one solution $(X,Y)$) to the equation

$Y = mX + c$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are integers, but $m$ and $c$ are irrational. Could anyone point me in any direction as to how to proceed?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for integers $X$ and $Y$ that satisfy the above equation, when $m$ and $c$ are known.

Comment: solving? for what variable?

Comment: For X and Y; I'll edit that in to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: how did you prove that the solution is actually unique?

Comment: Proof by contradiction: say there exist two distinct solutions $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$. Then we have
$$Y_1 = mX_1 + c$$
$$Y_2 = mX_2 + c$$

Subtracting the second equation from the first produces

$$Y_1 - Y_2 = m(X_1 - X_2)$$

So we have integer = irrational x integer, which is not possible.

Comment: Obviously, there is no solution for general $m$ and $c$. (If there were, then the irrationals would be countable.) It has no strictly algebraic or analytic solution. You are going to need number theory techniques.

Comment: Thanks, but would you be able to elaborate on why the irrationals need to be countable?